# При попытке вызова метода класса-наследника появляется ошибка - метод не найден в базовом классе (через указатель на базовый класс)

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

Есть базовый класс "Си-строка":

```
class C_STRING
{
    protected:
        char * array;
        int length;
    public:
        ...
};
```

От него унаследован класс "Битовая строка" (нули и единицы в качестве char-символов), в котором определён метод смены знака в числе:

```
class STR_BIT : public C_STRING
{
    public:
        ...
        void ChangeSign ();
};
```

В .cpp-файле метод определён как:

```
void STR_BIT :: ChangeSign () {...}
```

По заданию нужно выделить массив указателей на базовый класс и заполнить его как объектами базового класса, так и производного. Массив указателей из C_STRING * элементов, выделяю память через new STR_BIT или new C_STRING. Объекты вроде как создаются без ошибок. При обращении к методу ChangeSign () через указатель на базовый класс компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

```
error: 'class C_STRING' has no member named 'ChangeSign'
```

Почему метод не найден в производном классе, что его приходится искать в базовом? Как решить проблему?

Comment: Ну вы же не определили метод в базовом классе, чего вы хотите? Изучите ООП хотя бы на базовом уровне, который даётся во всех нормальных книгах по Си++. То, о чём вы говорите, называется полиморфным наследованием (с таблицами виртуальных функций и восходящим приведением). Гуглите. Абстрактный класс создаётся через создание чистой виртуальной функции, но это уже для создания интерфейса.

Comment: "При вызове метода через объект дочернего класса, компилятор сначала смотрит, существует ли этот метод в дочернем классе. Если нет, то он начинает продвигаться по цепочке наследования вверх и проверяет, был ли этот метод определён в любом из родительских классов."
Если метод определён в дочернем классе, то он не должен искаться в базовом. Ответа на вопрос "почему метод не найден" не вижу.

Comment: Если ты вызываешь через указатель на базовый класс, а метод не виртуальный, то динамического связывания не будет, вот и весь ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить абстрактный метод в базовый класс (или дать ему какую-то дефолтную реализацию) либо использовать `dynamic_cast`.

Доки:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: Или `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual void method() { }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   void method() override { }
};
```